# Is it possible to resize a UITableViewCell without using UITableViewDelegate?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to resize my table view cells from inside the cell instead of from the `UITableViewDelegate`. I am resizing them based on asynchronous content, so I can't size them in the delegate.

I tried setting `self.frame` inside the cell, but the table view was really unhappy about that. Cells were overlapping and all kinds of craziness was going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply have to use the table view to control height.  You can tell the table a cell has altered by using the calls to remove and then re-add specific cells, so you don't have to reload the whole table - but the height has to be fetched using the delegate callback tableView:heightForRow:atIndexPath:

I don't see why this is not practical though.  You can have any number of asynch systems running that update a central height cache held by the table view delegate - every time you create a cell you can assign it the delegate as a reference so it has a way to talk back to the table and let it know cells need reloading and what the new heights are.

If you think about it, the poor table view is a scroll view that has to manage all these separate cells and keep them together visually - so it's really unkind of a cell to go rogue and start altering frames without letting the table view know what is going on anyway.  It's best to let the table drive and tell it what to do.

Comment: Yeah, if you call [tableView reloadData] it'll call the delegate method `tableView:heightForRow:atIndexPath:` where you have a chance to calculate the appropriate cell heights based on your data. Bear in mind though, this can get expensive in terms of scrolling performance if you have very tall cells or a lot of them.

Comment: Which is why the height cache part is really important, so you don't have to do a lot of work to tell the system what heights are.

Comment: You dont need to call [tableView reloadData], as Canada Dev suggests.  Rather, you can call [tableView beginUpdates]; [tableView endUpdates]; which will cause the tableView to re-measure each cell (call heightForForRow:atIndexPath: for each cell) without reloading each cell.

Comment: Does it reload cells when heights change?  An interesting approach.

Answer (score 1):

No you can not set the cell's size without using the `UITableViewDelegate`. Changing the size of the cell with actually change the size of the cell, but it will not change the offsets that the `UITableView` draws the cells with. Which will result in overlaps, and gaps all over the place.

Your friend is `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, and it should be *fast*. If you override it, then the table view can no longer make the assumption that all rows are of the same height. And thus it must query *all* rows for their height each time it fetches cells to draw.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to manage the cells contentView propertys frame, instead of the cells frame itself
heres a reference http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/contentView

Comment: I am adding views in the contentView. I am resizing `self.frame` instead of `self.contentView.frame` because the contentView auto-resizes with the autoResizingMask.

Either way, setting the frame of `self.view` or `self.contentView` doesn't fix the issue. The tableView still is super confused if you size it from inside the cell.